# Call a method from another class through a button gets an unhandled exception

Tags: c#, class, methods, xamarin

So I have two classes: `HomeActivity.cs` and `MainActivity.cs`.

Under `HomeAcitivity.cs`, I have this code:

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

ImageButton btnGallery = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imageButton1);
btnGallery.Click += main.ButtonOnClickGallery;

if (IsThereAnAppToTakePictures())
{
     CreateDirectoryForPictures();
     ImageButton btnCamera = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imageButton2);
     btnCamera.Click += main.ButtonOnClickCamera;
}

Button btnSkip = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSkip);
btnSkip.Click += delegate { StartActivity(typeof(NoPhoto)); };
```

If you click the button, it will redirect to the method in the `MainActivity.cs`. The problem is it gives an `Unhandled expception: Java.Lang.NullPointerException`.

Code in `MainActivity.cs`:

```
public void ButtonOnClickGallery(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var intent = new Intent();
    intent.SetType("image/*");
    intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
    StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE); // unhandled exception
}

public void ButtonOnClickCamera(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
    App._file = new File(App._dir, String.Format("myPhoto_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));
    intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(App._file));
    StartActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA); // unhandled exception
}
```

The line where it points is in `StartActivityForResult()`, probably because it leads to another method.

What I expect is after clicking the button, it'll then perform the method and then show the image (purpose of the method) to the `Main.axml` (`MainActivity.cs`).

Why does this happen? And what is the best way to do the method calling from one class to another (without having to return again to the first class that started the calling)?

Let me know if my question is too vague. Hopefully get a solution to this.

Comment: Actually, you get a NullReferenceException...

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes, any idea how to properly call a method in another class that has a method inside?

Comment: At which line you are getting exception?  How are you assigning a handler to Button Click event with a function which has mismatching signature? "btnSkip.Click += delegate { StartActivity(typeof(NoPhoto)); };"

Comment: OK, as Giorgi offered an answer already, I'll just add a general explantaion... You get this exception because anywhere in your program, a reference variable is accessed that actually is set to `null`. This *could* have been due to having forgot to set a property in the intent variable appropriately. In the concrete case, StartActivity sets some internal variable we are not aware of to an appropriate value that otherwise would have remained null (as in your code).

Comment: @Nair It calls another class.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because you are manually creating `MainActivity` in your code. You should instead use `StartActivity` to open `MainActivity`:

```
StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
```

If you want MainActivity to automatically open camera or picture chooser you can pass additional data that MainActivity can use to decide what to do.

```
   var main = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
   main.PutExtra("OpenCamera", true);
   StartActivity(main);
```

Inside `MainActivity` OnCreate you can get the data like this:

```
bool openCamere = Intent.GetBooleanExtra("OpenCamera", false);
```

Comment: I just got home so sorry for the late comment. And sorry for asking since I'm really new to this but how do I call the method `ButtonOnClickCamera` after inserting the codes above?

Comment: @UrieP.: You can call ButtonOnClickCamera from OnCreate

Comment: is this calling correct? `ButtonOnClickGallery(this, new EventArgs(), openGallery);` because after clicking the gallery button, it redirects to the camera then when I clicked the 'x' to exit, it then redirects to the gallery.

Comment: I changed the string to var because it says it cannot convert boolean into string. `var openGallery = Intent.GetBooleanExtra("OpenGallery", false);`